# Bytes are invalid for 'unprotect'-function after being saved in a txt-file

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, password-protection

I want to save encoded user-credentials in a txt-file for later use, and delete this file when the user loggs out.
Here is my code for encrypting the data and writing it into txt-file:

```
// encrypt pw and username
Byte[] bUser = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(User);
Byte[] bPw = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(Pw);
// Generate additional entropy (will be used as the Initialization vector)
byte[] entropy = new byte[20];

using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rng.GetBytes(entropy);
}

byte[] cipheruser = ProtectedData.Protect(bUser, entropy,
    DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
byte[] cipherpw = ProtectedData.Protect(bPw, entropy,
    DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

//save pw and Username in file for later Use
// Create a new file     
File.WriteAllBytes(UserNameFile, cipheruser);
File.WriteAllBytes(PwFile, cipherpw);
```

But when I want to decrypt the data I get the error 'data is invalid', though it looks in the debugger the same way it was before being saved in a txt file.
Here is my decrypt-code:

```
byte[] entropy = new byte[20];
byte[] Userlines = File.ReadAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"LoginDataUserName.txt");
byte[] username = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Userlines, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
byte[] Pwlines = File.ReadAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"LoginDataPassWord.txt");
byte[] password = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Pwlines, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

Is the byte-data somehow changed through the saving? Can it be avoided or are there better methods for storing encrypted user credentials?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where are you getting `entropy` from in the read example? And is it running as the same user?

Comment: Yes it is running as the same user. The entropy is hard coded in the class. Its the same as the encoding. I forgot to mention it in the description.

Comment: The entropy in the first case is randomly generated. Are you definitely taking the correct random value and using it in the second case?

Comment: Please update your question then. You're randomly generating entropy in the write code, and we don't know where the entropy is coming from in the read code. If you're not using the same entropy, you won't be able to unprotect the values. Did you store the entropy somewhere?

Comment: Also, you're using UserNameFile and PwFile in the write code, and paths and names in the read code. Double-check that you're actually reading the files you wrote the data to.

Comment: Surely it'd be easier to use one of the existing "user session state" mechanisms for this, than wearing out your server hard disk writing text files endlessly..